# Unable to connect NextCloud to OnlyOffice document server

Tags: nextcloud, onlyoffice

When trying to connect NextCloud to OnlyOffice's document server, an error is thrown, but not much else is provided in order to fix the issue.

[image: NextCloud - Error when trying to connect]

As shown below, the server is running properly, on HTTPS (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50766990/how-to-properly-set-up-https-for-onlyoffice) for steps followed to set up certificate), and on a different server.

[image: OnlyOffice document server running properly]

Docker instances have been reset, all should be working [as per documentation](http://www.onlyoffice.com/blog/2017/03/how-to-connect-onlyoffice-online-editors-to-nextcloud/).

Is the issue on the NextCloud or OnlyOffice side? What could be done to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you post the Nextcloud logs please?

Comment: See this [Github gist](https://gist.github.com/jansensan/a47045f014ce6dc8905abd468adbeaf9), these are the relevant logs to my latest attempts in Settings > Logging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding Let’s Encrypt Authority X3 intermediate certificate to the DocumentServer or

```
'onlyoffice' =>
  array (
    'verify_peer_off' => TRUE,
  )
```

to the /var/www/nextcloud/config/config.php

BTW your document server is accessible from outside network.
We would recommend to enable JWT

Comment: There is a lot of information missing for me to understand what to do here: the `var/www` directory of my VPS is completely empty, is the `nextcloud` directory supposed to have been generated when installing DocumentServer on Docker? Also, what is JWT, and where would I enable this? If it is recommended, why is it not set by default when installing the DocumentServer?

Comment: Ok, so it seems that I was misunderstanding the first option. I thought that the change was supposed to be set inside of some OO DocumentServer setup, but in fact it was meant to be done in the `config.php` of the NextCloud instance. So that works, I can now view and edit files from NC. I am still curious about what is JWT, if there is doc, etc. I will mark this answer as what resolved my issue.